# Adding a Hold option to task outcome, not available in SPD

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, tasks

I'm working on a workflow with SharePoint Designer. I have added a "Hold" option to the `Task Outcome` field, but the option isn't appearing in the Task Outcome options in SharePoint Designer (2013). I had previously done this for another workflow on another site collection, and the option appeared properly.

Is there a time delay between when the option appears, and is there a way to force SPD to update the field's options?

Comment: did you create the custom content type and custom site column?

Comment: I added "Hold" to the SharePoint Workflow Column

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work, you can try creating custom CT, site column with Task Options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set **Yes** under "Update all content types inheriting from this type" for the **Task Outcome** field. After that, create a 2013 workflow again, it should have this outcome option.
[image]

If this issue still exists, you can create a new custom workflow task(SharePoint 2013) content type and create a new TaskOutcome field and set options for the field and then create a 2013 workflow using this custom workflow task content type.
[Create custom outcome options in workflow tasks for SharePoint 2013 workflow](http://www.suhail.cloud/2014/06/create-custom-outcome-options-in.html)

Comment: This is what I missed! I didn't update the Site's content type, just the subsite's column!